# Initializing reference variables in initialization list

Tags: c++, class, variables, reference, initialization

I have three .cpp files: Game, Guesser, and Provider. Each one of the header files for those contains its respective class declaration.

In my Game class, I need private variables for Guesser and Provider.

Guesser has a non-default constructor

`Guesser::Guesser (int wordLength, const char* wordListFilename){}`

so I have to initialize it through an initialization list on the Game constructor.

What I have so far:

`Guesser& guesser;`

`Provider& provider;`

```
`Game::Game(int& wordLength, const char* filename, const Provider& providr) : guesser(wordLength, filename),provider(providr)
{
    numMissedGuesses = 0;
    wordSoFar = string(wordLength, FILL_CHARACTER);
}`
```

This code doesn't compile, and I'm lost on where to go from here.

**Error messages from compiler:**

||=== Build: Debug in adthangman (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

error: 'guesser' declared as reference but not initialized|

error: 'provider' declared as reference but not initialized|

In constructor 'Game::Game(int, const char*, const Provider&)':|

error: expression list treated as compound expression in mem-initializer [-fpermissive]|
warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]|

error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Guesser&' from expression of type 'const char*'|

error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Provider&' from expression of type 'const Provider'|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `guesser` shouldn't be a reference.

Comment: I can't declare it any other way without getting an error that I haven't met the format of the constructor.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Best guess I have for `guesser` is that the type is incomplete. The compiler is pretty clear on `provider`.

Comment: Chris, it does mention that the type is incomplete when I do:
Guesser guesser;

I've just started learning C++, so I have no idea what to do. I've spent two days on this to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guesser` and `provider` need to be declared inside the `class Game { }` scope if they are to be initialized by the constructor.

You can't initialize a reference to a class object by providing arguments to the constructor of its class, though. References must be initialized by a preexisting object. (Non-member references can also be initialized by temporary objects, but that's a bit different.)

Also, reference members are often a red flag for class design. You might want to use regular member objects for `guesser` and `provider` instead of references.

```
class Game {
    Guesser guesser;
    Provider provider;
};
```

Comment: guesser and provider are declared inside the class Game, and they are required to be private. I'm getting a, "class 'Game' does not have any field named 'provider'" error.

Comment: @James I've provided an example of declaring the objects as members of the class. Is that what you have? Because the symptoms you describe all point to missing those declarations. Note, you don't also define them outside the class afterward.

Comment: And error: field 'guesser' has incomplete type.
error: filed 'provider' has incomplete type.

Comment: @James That means the `Guesser` and `Provider` classes haven't been defined yet. Their definitions need to come before an object can be instantiated. (But the member functions can be defined later.)

Comment: They are definitely defined as far as I know. I'm only allowed to modify the Game.cpp and Game.h files. The Guesser and Provider classes were created for me, so I'm literally just adding class Guesser and class Provider to my header file where my Game class is defined.

Comment: @James The only way for a class to be incomplete is that it's not defined. Please proceed from the assumption that it is undefined in that context. You might be missing a `#include` directive, for example, causing the definition to be invisible at that point.

Comment: Wow...... You were right. I thought if the files were in the same project that I could add the:
class Guesser;
class Provider;
without including the header files. Once I included the headers, all of the errors cleared and the code compiled with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a constructor on an object that is a reference.  It in itself is not the object, but is points to another object.  So either pass the reference guesser variable another object of class type guesser or change it to a regular variable.  Also you can't assign a const object to a non constant reference. Make the provider parameter non constant.

Comment: I can create Provider provider as a regular variable since it has a default construction.

I can't create Guesser guesser as a regular variable because it throws the error "no matching function for call to Guesser:Guesser();

Comment: @James Default construction shouldn't be an issue. You already have the constructor arguments when the `Game` constructor is called.